# Code Igniter - How to save images into database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm making use of codeIgniter to upload files into folders in the server. Now I also want to save the data into the database, what do I need in order to get the raw data and then save it into the database?

Here's the model for saving files:

```
<?php
class files extends ci_Model{
    function saves($filename, $filedata, $post_id){
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_files SET file_data='$filedata', filename='$filename', postid='$post_id'");
    }
}
?>
```

Here's how I call it from the upload controller:

```
$filename = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
$file_data = file_get_contents($data['upload_data']['file_name']);

$this->load->model('files');
$this->files->saves($filename, $file_data, 'ID1');
```

Table Structure:

- file_data (LONG BLOB)
- filename (VARCHAR)

Comment: Why don't you just save the path to the image, not the image itself? The performance will be better. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: They say it's more secure when you store it on the database plus it's also portable, you won't have to worry about the filesystem structure when you change from one operating system to another

Comment: I wouldn't because something can easily go wrong when save it to the database. To aid security you could always save the images above the htdocs folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using the handy mysql_real_escape_string() like this:

```
$filename = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
$file_data = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($data['upload_data']['full_path']));
```

Answer (score 2):

Storing Path is very best method.
But if you want to try ....

It is same as in PHP or CodeIgniter ,

Better I give you the link, then writing code here: http://www.techcubetalk.com/2009/01/tutorial-on-how-to-store-images-in-mysql-blob-field/

Answer (score 1):

Try it , it's work on my code`

```
function _save($id = null){

    $config['upload_path'] = './asset/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);    

        if($_POST || $_FILES){
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('field_input_name')){
                echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
            } else {
                $w = $this->upload->data();
                $data = array(
                    'field_input_name' => $w['file_name'],
                    );
                 $this->db->insert('table_image', $data); 
            }
        }
```

}