# How to save image in mysql with codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So far, always saved a path for the images in the database, but this time, I have to save the actual image in the database. I prepared a field for that in my table(longblob)

I have this code in my controller:

```
 $insertWhat = array(

   'dsrequestFileName1'  => $this->input->post('dsrequestFileName1'),
   'dsrequestFile1'      => isset($_FILES['dsrequestFile1']['name'])? $_FILES['dsrequestFile1']['name'] : '',
   'dsrequestFileName2'  => $this->input->post('dsrequestFileName2'),
   'dsrequestFile2'      => isset($_FILES['dsrequestFile2']['name'])? $_FILES['dsrequestFile2']['name'] : ''
 );

 $now = date('Y-m-d-His');
 $valid_extensions = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp','');
 if($insertWhat['dsrequestFile1'] !=""){    
     if (!in_array(end(explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['dsrequestFile1']['name']))), $valid_extensions)) {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('wrongtype', '<p class=error>Wrong type of file has been uploaded! Only gif, jpg, bmp and png are allowed.</p>');
         redirect('somepage/somefunctionHere');
     }
     $insertWhat['dsrequestFile1'] = str_replace(' ', '_',$insertWhat['dsrequestFile1']);
     $insertWhat['dsrequestFile1'] = $now.$insertWhat['dsrequestFile1'];
 }

 $config['upload_path'] = 'somefolder/imagesfolder';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png';
 $config['max_size']    = '2048';
 $config['max_width']  = '1024';
 $config['max_height']  = '768';
 $config['file_name'] = $insertWhat['dsrequestFile1'];
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
 $this->upload->initialize($config);   
 // perform the upload
 $this->upload->do_upload('dsrequestFile1');
 $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data('dsrequestFile1'));
 // code that saves the insert data is irrelevant to the question, I can post it here if needed however.
```

However, this code only upload the image. What should I change here so I can save the image in the database. I don't want to upload the image if that is possible.

Nothing on this in CI manual unfortunately.

Comment: Duplicate. Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737384/code-igniter-how-to-save-images-into-database

Comment: use query to do this. after upload take the file name, save in database.

Comment: I did check that page, but the link provided there is broken, and the solution doesn't work.

Comment: try this http://w3code.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-codeigniter/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I store images in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472233/can-i-store-images-in-mysql)

Comment: @Rakesh, do you have any idea if it is mandatory image to be uploaded, or I can omit that part of the code?

Comment: @Parry, thanks to the link, it was really helpful.

Comment: @user2417624 Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello Please try this code

```
   if($this->input->post('update_list'))
    {
      if($this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic'))
      {
            $image_file = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $img_name=file_get_contents($image_file); /* This function move to image in your database*/


             $this->your_mode->add_image_table($img_name);// pass image as parameter to your model
       }

    }
```